# When i add my function to functions.php wp-admin show white screen only

Tags: wordpress, function

Hello i have small problem, i try to do a custom pagination, but when i add my function in to functions.php admin page goes white, weird think is that on my friend Computer admin page work's but when he try to save he has white screen also

```
    function custom_pagination($numpages='', $pagerange='', $paged='') {

  if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
  }

  global $paged;
  if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
  }

  if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$numpages) {
            $numpages = 1;
        }
  }

  $pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'          => 'page/%#%/',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => True,
    'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
  );

  $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

  if ($paginate_links) {
    $showpagination = "";
    $showpagination .= "<nav class='custom-pagination'>";
     // echo "<span class='page-numbers page-num'>Page " . $paged . " of " . $numpages . "</span> ";
    $showpagination .= $paginate_links;
    $showpagination .= "</nav>";
  }else{
     $showpagination = "";
  }

  return $showpagination;

}
```

Comment: Most probably you have a syntax error somehwere. Turn on error reporting and you'll know more.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code itself. Could you give us some more?

Answer (score 0):

You have some extra whitespace outside of `<?php` or `?>`. Check if there's a space at the end of the file.

Else check for spaces before any `<?php` or after any `?>`

Comment: excess whitespace does not result in an empty page.

Comment: Yes it will, you'll get a 'Can't modify headers, headers already sent' error.

Comment: Correct, but that is only a notice, it will not halt the execution of the code. A blank page is the result of a fatal error and the only way to find that is with error reporting.